# Evaluating $\int {{{dx} \over {x\sqrt {x - 1} }}} $

Tags: calculus

$$\int {{{dx} \over {x\sqrt {x - 1} }}} $$
$$u = {x^{{1 \over 2}}}$$
$$du = {1 \over 2}{x^{{{ - 1} \over 2}}}dx$$
$$dx = 2{x^{{1 \over 2}}}du = 2udu$$
$$\eqalign{
  &  = \int {{{2udu} \over {{u^2}\sqrt {{u^2} - 1} }}}   \cr 
  &  = 2\int {{{du} \over {u\sqrt {{u^2} - 1} }}}   \cr 
  &  = 2{\sec ^{ - 1}}\left| u \right| + C  \cr 
  &  = 2{\sec ^{ - 1}}\left| {\sqrt x } \right| + C \cr} $$

The answer should be $$2{\tan ^{ - 1}}\left| {\sqrt {x - 1} } \right| + C$$

What is wrong with the steps?

Comment: @AhmedAli: How about trying $u = x-1$ instead?

Comment: I already knew the other solution... I was just wondering why this is different

Comment: Trying $u=x-1$ would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\text{arcsec}{\sqrt{x}} = \arctan{\sqrt{x-1}} + \text{constant}$$

Comment: You know, with your current user name... when you get to 100k someone will start a meta thread "Congratulations to Please delete account for the 100K!" :-)

Comment: @Please delete account
when I try to differentiate arcsec it gives a different result

Comment: @AhmedAli [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%282*arcsec%28sqrt%28x%29%29%29)

Comment: Thank you, for some reason online calculators don't get it right (probably because I'm not typing it right). Did it manually and it worked.